# Where I can get historical jet fuels prices?

Tags: usa, fuel, cost, russia

I would like to analyze jet fuels prices in 2014.

Where can I get jet fuel prices for 2014, only in USA and Russia?

As there are different types of fuels, it would be okay to get prices for one (believe, trends are the same) or for all types.

Comment: Quite good question that should also be on [open data.SE](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 19):

U.S. Energy Information Administration [keeps tabs](http://www.eia.gov/dnav/pet/pet_pri_refoth_dcu_nus_m.htm) on most refined and crude prices including kerosene-type jet fuel. For those who hail from metric units' land, these are in dollars per gallon.

[image: Price history]

Comment: Eek! Why not a log graph?

Comment: @bjb568 - oil companies would have liked a straight log graph. Pilots and passengers, not so much.

Comment: I'll bet that is nearly the same pattern as the regular oil price the news reports... didn't see that on the site, but interesting that AvGas & MoGas were the same price in 1980, now AvGas is 30% more...

Answer (score 6):

Although they don't have historical prices, [AirNav](http://www.airnav.com/) has a number of ways to view Jet A fuel prices [here](http://www.airnav.com/fuel/).

You might write them and ask if they will release historical prices to you.

Answer (score 6):

[Here](http://www.favt.ru/favt_new/?q=dejatelnost/ajeroporty_i_ajerodromy/ceny_na_aviagsm) is the data for Russian airports (unfortunately, in Russian).

Answer (score 2):

...and for anyone looking for historical data before 1975 (which is when the [data series at the US Energy Information Agency](https://www.eia.gov/dnav/pet/pet_pri_refoth_dcu_nus_m.htm) starts), [FRED provides the authoritative dataset](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/WPU0572):

[image]